# Fuzziness not behaving as expected in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, fuzzy-search, damerau-levenshtein

I am trying to test few test cases for my project which I am doing in Elasticsearch. The result given by the fuzziness query is confusing for a particular case :-
While searching for **Mall** keyword with fuzziness 2 applied in multi-match query its also matching **Mile**.

```
As per fuzziness documentation :-
=> 0 edits are allowed for string length is 0-2 .
=> 1 edit is allowed for  string length is 3-5.
=> 2 edits are allowed for string length greater than 5.
```

If this is the case why did **MILE** matched with **MALL**, because as per logic only one edit should be allowed and if we see for MALL->MILE we need 2 edits. 
Is Elasticsearch behaving as expected or am I missing something here. 
I am using simple whitespace analyzer for the field and query using

```
         {  "query": {
            "multi_match": {
                "query": "mall",
                "fields": [
                          "name"
                 ],
                 "fuzziness": 2
          } }}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation you have highlighted is only for when you specify [`"fuzziness": "AUTO"`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/common-options.html#fuzziness), otherwise if you specify a normal number (0, 1 or 2), then that number is taken into account (in your case, 2)

Comment: Thanks @Val got the clarity now.